# Display selection field according to the selection in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

how to display another selection field according to the selection of an option in a field in a native react form
Please Help 
Thanks

Comment: could you be more specific

Answer (score 0):

This isn't necessarily native-specific, it's just React state management. 
Very basically, perhaps something similar to:

```
<View>
  <MyInput onPress={() => this.setState({showField: !this.state.showField})} />
  {this.state.showField && <OtherField />}
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks but whats i want exactly if i have a field about country for example i choose america another field display all the city for america ?